# React - Saving a file client side from Axios request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have an API endpoint which is sending a PDF file.

On my client side, when a user clicks the download button, I want that PDF downloaded - I've found an approach using the code below, however wondering is this really the simplest way?

I've read about using `'Content-Disposition'` and tried it as an header in my API response however that doesn't work. `reply.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');`

(Btw the using Fastify)

So having this in my front end code after the POST request is complete, works:

```
const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = downloadUrl;
link.setAttribute('download', 'test.pdf'); 
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Is there no other simple/fewer lines of code approach?

UPDATE: I found this works https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver
Which I'm using like so:
(The most critical bit was `responseType: 'blob'` however there's a slight issue in that in my catch block, to pull the error message out the response I need to use `const errMessage = await new Blob([error.response.data]).text()`)

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/testing', requestBody, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/pdf'
                },
                responseType: 'blob'
            })
                .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
                    setIsSubmitting(false)

                    saveAs(response.data, "test.pdf")
                })
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is a package called 'react-pdf' which could do the above in few lines of code. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf   take a look at it, may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I usually do, I get my API to return the bytes and then on my client I have the following

```
images(id: string, cancelToken?: CancelToken): Promise<FileResponse> {
 let url_ = "pathtoendpoint/{id}";

 let options_ = <AxiosRequestConfig>{
   cancelToken,
   responseType: "blob",
   method: "GET",
   url: url_,
   headers: {
     Accept: "application/octet-stream",
     Authorization: "Bearer ezfsdfksf...."
   },
 };

  // You probably won't/shouldn't create a new axios object
  // on every request but it's here just to simplify things   
 return Axios.create().request(options_).then((_response: AxiosResponse) => 
 { 
   return new Promise<FileResponse>(_response.data);
 });

} 

export interface FileResponse {
  data: Blob;
  status: number;
  fileName?: string;
  headers?: { [name: string]: any };
}
```

From here I get my ephemeral DOM URI as so

```
let uri = URL.createObjectURL(data)
```

As you can see I *must* take this approach anyways if my image resource is behind `oAuth`

Once you have the uri, you should be able to save it. This approach also allows you return other metadata such as filename.

And, it allows you to handle errors more gracefully.